# How to define a value that represents a time value in c++ language / getdate()?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ubuntu

I would like to print the year,month,day,hour,min,second of a ctime data using getdate(). can someone five me an example of how to do this?

Here is the code:

```
how can i define the DATA as a struct date time? 
getdate(&DATE);
     printf("The year is : %d\n",DATE.da_year);
     printf("The month is : %d\n",DATE.da_month);
     printf("The day is : %d\n",DATE.da_day);
```

also can someone tell me how to convert from obj c to c++ the following:

```
(NSString *)conv_fromDateToString:(NSDate *)normalDate{ //code }
```

Comment: Assuming the getdate() you mean is this one: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getdate.html it does not do what you seem to think it does - read the documentation.

Comment: can you please tell me how to define a value that represents a time value ?(in c++ language)

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was incorrect.
You probably need [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=65).

Comment: @Neil: That tells how to construct a CTime object and how to extract data from a CTime object, is it not helpful?

Comment: @What are these CTime and CString things? Not part of Standard C++, for sure. And available on Ubuntu? Oh wait, could they be part of an antiquated framework that not even its misguided designers use any more?

Comment: @Neil: They are actually classes in MFC, I missed the `Ubuntu` tag. I will change the answer.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the library that contains CTime and CString?

Comment: I wanted to know how to extract data from a CTime object. @Als could you tell me how to add in a method definition the CTime object as a parameter. Then how to call this method with a given date in order to extract the y,m,h,s? I am working in Ubuntu

Comment: @marry: What is the `CTime` class you are reffering to? Let me sync up, since you asked what is the library that contains CTime?

Comment: do you have an answer to my question (ubuntu language). I need a method that takes as a parameter a date time value and returns a string with dd,yyyy,mmm,h,s. Please help:). Please write a method that takes a date as a parameter and workes with it:). That is what i don;t know. how to write a method that takes a date as a parameter.i would like an example too. i did have u the ideea of the method but is in obj c

Comment: @marry: What is the data type of the `date` parameter to this function you are trying to write?

Comment: I need to create a method thatt takes a time and retuns it with - :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * p = localtime( & t );
    cout << "year is " << 1900 + p->tm_year << " day is " << p->tm_wday << endl;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/ for further details.

Comment: THx for your answer. if i don't want the current time. if i have dd mm yy hh mm ss from the keyboard how to split it? i could also have dd/mm/yy...and so on:). i don't know the format for the time given from the keyboard.

Comment: and i would like to create a function calld convert from data to string that takes a data and returns the yyyy,mm,dd as a string

Comment: @marryy If you don't know the format, how can you expect to parse it? And the getdate() function I posted a link to will parse, but you need to read up on how to use it, we can't do everything for you.

Comment: i know it has to be a ctime data:). the format should be the same with what ubuntu supports:). a ctime data for example!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're asking.  If the `getdate` function you're
asking about is the X/Open one, then it takes a `char const*` as an
argument; in C++, this would usually be obtained by calling `c_str()` on
an `std::string`.  The function actually takes a number of other
arguments, however, by various devious means; in particular, the
environment variable `DATEMSK` must have been set, either by the use before
starting your application, or by calling `setenv` (or `putenv`) from
your application.

Note that this variable specifies the name of a file, which `getdate`
reads to obtain templates for parsing the time and date.

The function returns a pointer to a `tm`, the standard Unix broken-down
time and date structure.  A null pointer is returned to indicate an
error, with the error code in a global variable `getdate_err`.

All of which implies a lot of static data, and a total lack of thread
safety.  This looks like one of those legacy Unix functions, defined
back in the days when threads didn't exist, and which are fundamentally
broken when viewed from a modern perspective.  Unlike most of the others
in this case, however, there doesn't seem to be a thread safe
replacement.

Anyway, for the exact specification of `getdate`, see the [Posix-X/Open specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getdate.html),
and for the specification of `tm` (or `struct tm`, since this is part of
a C API), see specification of `time.h` in the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html) or
the C standard.